# Rewire - Mock Dependency In Same Module

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking

Say I have a module with two functions with one depending on the other:

```
// example.js
function A() {
    return "hello";
}

function B() {
    return A();
}

module.exports.B = B;
```

Can I use rewire to mock the call to A() in B()?

```
// example.test.js
var assert = require('chai').assert,
    rewire = require('rewire'),
    example = rewire('./example.js');

example.__set__({
    A: function( return 'goodbye';),
});

describe('test B in example.js', function() {
    it('should return "goodbye"', function() {
        assert.strictEqual(example.B(), 'goodbye');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this does work. I'm not sure what solved the problem exactly. Previously I was exporting the dependent function as part of a function prototype (e.g. `function.prototype.dependentFunction = function() { };`) and somehow this was messing with rewire. I redefined my function by declaring/defining it first and then attaching it to the model:

```
function dependentFunction() { ... }
exportedObject.prototype.dependentFunction = dependentFunction();
```

Doing this fixed my problems.